# Array Elements displaying in single line

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple JSON from which I would like to render values on every single line. Although, right now I have the entire thing showing up in one line and not the way I expected. What would I need to do to overcome this and get it to work the way I intend it to. Here is the code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import './category.css';
import { IoMdArrowDropdown } from 'react-icons/io';
import { GoTriangleUp } from 'react-icons/go';
import dummyData from '../../../json_data/dummy_data.json'

const SearchBox = () => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [dropDownValue, setDropDownValue] = useState(null);

    const onSelect = (value) => {
        setDropDownValue(value);
        setOpen(!open);
    };

    return (
        <div className="box_category">
            <div className="category_caption">Categories</div>
            <div className="block_drop">
                <div className="category_dropdown">
                    <div className="category_box">            
                        {dropDownValue === null ? "Enter Category" : dropDownValue}                     
                    </div>
                    <div className="category_dropIcon" onClick={() => setOpen(prev => !prev)}>
                        {open ? <GoTriangleUp size={"22px"} /> : <IoMdArrowDropdown size={"30px"} />}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className={open ? "category_option" : "category_option_block"}>
                    {dummyData.map((key, values) => <div className="select_options" onClick={() => onSelect(dummyData[values].types )}>
                        {dummyData[values].types} //This is where the array values get fetched
                    </div>
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default SearchBox;
```

I'm trying to map over the values of `types`.

The JSON:

```
[
    {
        "district": "Kolkata",
        "types": [
            "Grievances",
            "General",
            "Urgent",
            "Service"
        ],
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your JSON data with this;

```
{
    "district": "Kolkata",
    "types": [
        "Grievances",
        "General",
        "Urgent",
        "Service"
    ],
}
```

and then change your code block where you used map function with this;

```
<div className={open ? "category_option" : "category_option_block"}>
                    {dummyData.types.map((type) => <div className="select_options" onClick={() => onSelect(type)}>
                        {type} //This is where the array values get fetched
                    </div>
                    )}
                </div>
```

This will create a seperate div instance for every element inside types array